# printing elements of a queue using <list> (error C2760)

Tags: c++, queue, doubly-linked-list

Trying to implement a queue using a doubly-linked list from `<list>`, and I'm getting the following error for my `print()` function: `error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected ';'`

The code for the Queue class is:

```
#ifndef DLL_QUEUE
#define DLL_QUEUE
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Queue {
public:
    Queue() {
    }
    void clear() {
        lst.clear();
    }
    bool isEmpty() const {
        return lst.empty();
    }
    T& front() {
        return lst.front();
    }
    T dequeue() {
        T el = lst.front();
        lst.pop_front();
        return el;
    }
    void enqueue(const T& el) {
        lst.push_back(el);
    }
    void print() {
        for (list<T>::const_iterator i = this->front(); i != this->back(); ++i)
            cout << *i;
        cout << "\n";
    }
private:
    list<T> lst;
};
#endif
```

The main method that is calling the class is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "genQueue.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    //"genQueue.h"
    Queue<int> *queue1 = new Queue<int>();
    for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++)
        queue1->enqueue(k);
    queue1->print();



    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @GauravSehgal tried that and it didn't work. Also tried `for (list<T>::const_iterator i = lst.front(); i != lst.back(); ++i)` and that didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a good look at the `print` function:

```
void print() {
    for (list<T>::const_iterator i = this->front(); i != this->back(); ++i)
        cout << *i;
    cout << "\n";
}
```

You've defined a member method `T& Queue<T>::front`, which you attempt to call when you write `this->front()`. However, `T&` is not assignable to `List<T>::const_iterator`. Additionally, `this->back()` attempts to call a method `Queue<T>::back()`, which doesn't exist.

The reason these errors don't manifest until you try to call `print()` is because the compiler will only *instantiate* templated code when it needs to. It won't try to instantiate a function you don't call, since the function might meaninglessly fail to compile for some types which you don't want to use.

---

If the goal is to iterate over the member list's contents, you can forget about all the above complexity and use a fool-proof [ranged for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), which is much simpler:

```
void print() {
    for (const T& t : lst){
        cout << t;
    }
}
```

On another note, there is no reason to dynamically allocate the queue using `new`. Note that you don't `delete` the queue and thus have a memory leak. You should store the queue on the stack, by value, if possible, to avoid silly pointer mistakes:

```
Queue<int> queue1;
for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++)
    queue1.enqueue(k);
queue1.print();
```

If you *really* need the queue to exist on the heap, consider using `std::unique_ptr<Queue<T>>` or `std::shared_ptr<Queue<T>>` for pointers that automatically manage their lifetime and ownership.

Additionally, take a look at [system(“pause”); - Why is it wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong).

Comment: This was very helpful! I didn't know those kinds of for-loops existed